# Extrating text with textract from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to retrieve a `.doc` file from a s3 bucket and use `textract` to read its text. In order to do so, I created these two functions:

```
def process_files(filepath):
   s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
   filename = 's3://' + bucket_name + '/' + filepath
   _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
   if ext == '.pdf':
       extract_string = pdf_to_string(s3, filename)
       return extract_string
   elif ext == '.doc':
       extract_string = doc_to_string(s3, filename)
       return extract_string

def doc_to_string(s3_file, filename):
   """
   convert an .doc or .docs file into string
   """
   print(filename)
   print(s3_file.ls('/myname/test_files/*'))
   text = textract.process(filename)

   return text
```

However, I am getting the error:

> > Is this the right path/to/file/you/want/to/extract.doc

**Therefore** I changed my code in order to change the path:

```
def doc_to_string(s3_file, filename):
   """
   convert an .doc or .docs file into string
   """
   text = textract.process(s3_file.ls('/myname/test_files/*'))
   return text
```

But I get:

> > Path should be string bytes or os.pathlike

Comment: Always post your full error log here. It will help debug the code.

Comment: Which line is generating the error? What is in `textract.process()`? Why do you wish to use `s3fs` rather than the boto3 AWS SDK?